# PySide/PyDev not autcompleting correctly

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pyside

i have a problem with pyside and pydev. when i press ctrl+space shortcut i can see the PySide package, but when i put the dot and press ctrl-space again the autocompletion dosen't works.

[image: autocomplete not even shown]

My imports:

```
from PySide import QtCore,QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import *
```

Comment: You may not have imported the package correctly ensure that your imports are setup with correct as declaration if used.

Comment: Does auto completion work with the built in data structures? If so this is a strong indication that something in your project setup isn't jiving with your ide regarding that particular api

Comment: it looks like you are importing these modules into the global namespace. try removing the PySide. and just ctrl space without any object reference

Comment: @TommyDDD it's only happening with PySide

Comment: For a quick test trying using something like from PySide import QtCore as Core and then reference the object using Core.

Comment: @TommyDDD i have tried, and autocompletion doesn't recognize or show Core

Answer (score 0):

Autocompletion only works if you directly imported the module. So for your imports, autocomplete would work after typing `QtCore.` or `QtGui.`, but not for `PySide.`. If you want autocompletion for the latter, you need to add `import PySide`.